# How can I receive notification that my service is being uninstalled?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I would like to know if it is possible to receive notification that my service is being uninstalled?

I can receive notification that my service is being stopped.

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
```

but how can I tell if it's being uninstalled?

Comment: you mean shutdown in otherway ?

Comment: Go to the installer code, if -u is passed, it is being uninstalled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4828786/kevin - can you be more explicit... where is this code passed in to the service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out custom parameters can be called from an installer using the Service Control (sc) command:

```
 sc control <name_of_service> 129
```

Where 129 is a custom code that is handled by your service:

```
    protected enum customCommands
    {
        install = 128,
        uninstall = 129,
    }

    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
    {
        base.OnCustomCommand(command);

        if (command >= 128 && command <= 255)
        {
            customCommands cust = (customCommands)command;

            switch (cust)
            {
                case customCommands.install:
                    break;

                case customCommands.uninstall:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```